# Navigating website with HtmlUnit after logging in with WebRequest

Tags: htmlunit

I had issues using HtmlUnit's click functionality to log in using the form, so I decided to log in using a WebRequest instead.

The way the site logs in is that the submit button for the form is an ajax call to a separate URL. Once the response from that POST request is received, the page reloads automatically and you are logged in.

```
// Client configuration
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

// Get cookies (Not sure if necessary to log in)
    HtmlPage webPage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("https://www.marinetraffic.com/");
    URL cookieURL = new URL("https://www.marinetraffic.com/");
    String cookies = webClient.getCookies(cookieURL).toString();

// Configure request headings
    URL url = new URL("https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/users/ajax_login");
    WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(url, HttpMethod.POST);

    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader(":authority", "www.marinetraffic.com");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader(":method", "POST");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader(":path", "/en/users/ajax_login");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader(":scheme", "https");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("accept", "*/*");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("cookie", cookies);
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("origin", "https://www.marinetraffic.com");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("referer", "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/home/centerx:-33.1/centery:21.4/zoom:4");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");

// Request body with form information  
    requestSettings.setRequestBody("_method=POST&email=dummy%40gmail.com&password=fakepassword&is_ajax=true");


// redirectPage is of type UnexpectedPage
    Page redirectPage = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 1000);

// Console confirms login was a success
    System.out.println(redirectPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
    System.out.println(webClient.getCookies(cookieURL).toString());

// When I try to navigate to the main page I am not logged in
    HtmlPage webPage2 = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("https://www.marinetraffic.com/");
    System.out.println(webPage2.asXml());
```

I've also tried doing a WebRequest GET call with the updated cookies to the main site, but that also returned an UnexpectedPage. Now that I've logged in correctly, how would I go about getting an HtmlPage to navigate the website?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to interact like a normal user with this page

- get the page
- locate the sign in element
- click on the sign in element
- locate the input fields
- type your userid and password into the fiels
- locate and click the sign in button

Maybe you have to add some wait code somewhere.

Comment: I have already tried that to no avail, which is why I have resorted to using the request method instead.

I have waited for background javascript and have the resynchronizing ajax controller activated.